# Python-Disabling Action

Tags: python, pyqt

I am developing python plugins for **QGIS**. I am listing all the database connections to menu bar, using following code:

```
 for key in sorted( self.actionsDb.iterkeys(), key=lambda x: x.lower() ):
                    a = self.actionsDb[key]
                    self.menuDb.addAction(a)
                    a.setCheckable(True)
                    self.connect(a, SIGNAL("triggered(bool)"), self.dbConnectSlot)
```

On certain '**if**' condition, I want to make one of the actions **disabled** in the menu bar.

Example: under **Database** menu, we have two listed database connections:

```
Database
  -- localhost
  -- 192.168.5.6
```

I want to make some of them disabled depending on specific condition. I've tried `a.setCheckable(false)` with no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood you right, what you need is:

```
a.setEnabled(True/False)
```

Here's some additional info on `QAction` element: [QT Documentation:QAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#enabled-prop)